# What's the difference between Parameter Server Variables and Replicated Variables in Distributed Training?

Tags: tensorflow

When I read the section about "[Variable Distribution and Gradient Aggregation](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_models#variable_distribution_and_gradient_aggregation)" of high-performance model of tensorflow, I can not really tell the difference between [Parameter Server Variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_models#parameter_server_variables) and [Replicated Variables in Distributed Training](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_models#parameter_server_variables). Can someone explain them clearer?